# Warning: odbc_fetch_array() [Microsoft][ODBC Cursor Library] the instruction SELECT has a clause GROUP BY

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012-express

I'm trying to do a query with a sub-query that joins the results of many lines in one, in SQL Server.

When I run it on the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio it works great!

[Query running on the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHn7M.png)

But doing the same query with PHP, I receive this warning:

**Warning: odbc_fetch_array(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Cursor Library] the instruction SELECT has a clause GROUP BY, SQL state SL005 in SQLGetData**

The SQL:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(7),[Ficha_Tecnica].DataEntrega,111) as DataEntrega,  
[Ficha_Tecnica].CodigoCliente,  
[Ficha_Tecnica].CodTipoServico,  
count(*) as Contagem,  
[Ficha_Tecnica].NumeroOs,  
(SELECT CAST([Cartoes].Produto + ',' AS VARCHAR(400))
           FROM [Cartoes]
          WHERE [Cartoes].NumeroOS = [Ficha_Tecnica].NumeroOs
          ORDER BY [Cartoes].Produto
            FOR XML PATH('') ) AS Produto2 FROM Ficha_Tecnica  WHERE 1=1  and  Ficha_Tecnica.DataEntrega   >=  '2016-01-19'  
 and  Ficha_Tecnica.DataEntrega   <=  '2016-09-27'  
 GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(7),[Ficha_Tecnica].DataEntrega,111) 
, [Ficha_Tecnica].CodigoCliente 
, [Ficha_Tecnica].CodTipoServico 
, [Ficha_Tecnica].NumeroOs 
 ORDER BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(7),[Ficha_Tecnica].DataEntrega,111) asc
```

My PHP Version is 5.6.19

SQL Server 2012

Somebody have any clue of what can be happening?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've finally found the problem and the solution!
After four hours of trying!

I solved the problem making a CAST on the column I was making the sub-query:

```
CAST(
          (SELECT CAST([Cartoes].Produto + ',' AS VARCHAR(400))
           FROM [Cartoes]
          WHERE [Cartoes].NumeroOS = [Ficha_Tecnica].NumeroOs
          ORDER BY [Cartoes].Produto
            FOR XML PATH('') )

    AS VARCHAR(1000)) AS Produto2
```

What happens is that something wrong happens when we get a column too big from the SQL Server with PHP as the columns of the type "Text" or "VARCHAR (MAX)", for example!

So, that's it!

Tnx!